# Where to find lvl 30 items

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, tools

I was wondering where I could look up what lvl 30 items look like. I'm not an expert on D&D as i have only just started playing(about 8 months) but I was just curious as to what higher lvl play would be like.
I have looked in the D&D Compendium but I can't find all the items that I have seen mentioned in other websites, and forums, like the Longsword of the Conqueror +6 or the Godplate Armor of Negation.
I was wondering where people look up all this gear.

Where are they in the Compendium? If they're not there, what's the easiest way for a new player to realize they exist, without having encyclopedic knowledge of the manuals, and where can I find their description?

Comment: What are "all the items" you're referring to that you've seen mentioned?

Comment: I'm talking about Longsword of the Conqueror +6, Godplate Armor of negation. I don't see those in the DDI.

Comment: Hi. I've tried to make your question a little more spot-on, including the items you mentioned in you comment. If you thing I swayed the question too much from its original intent feel free to roll it back (then edit your comments in the question yourself, comments *will* get deleted sooner or later)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're missing is that Level 30 items, particularly Weapons/Implements, Neck, and Armor, are often 5+ or 15+ items.  The items you mentioned exist, but they exist (in both cases) as 15+ items- i.e., you could get a +3 version as a level 15 item, a +4 as a level 20, a +5 as a level 25, and a +6 as a level 30 item.  The Godplate<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=20)</sup> is just a Masterwork Armor type.  In this case, Armor of Negation<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=542)</sup> is from Adventurer's Vault, and is a 15+, and the Weapon of the Conqueror<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3062)</sup>, also a 15+, is in PHB: Dragonborn.  Very little out there is available as a level 30 and only as a level 30, and even less of it is good.

The other key thing is that higher level play isn't necessarily about new items, but about combinations.  Frost Weapons<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1363)</sup> are a 3+ weapon, but you could stick with them all the way through- in Paragon picking up Lasting Frost<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=316)</sup> as a feat, possibly Wintertouched<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=309)</sup> as a feat, Icy Heart<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=3730)</sup> as a feat, Siberys Shard of Merciless Cold<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=2503)</sup> (paragon), and Gloves of Ice<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1433)</sup> (paragon), then grabbing the Epic versions of the Shard and the Gloves.  Boom, once you've hit an enemy, you now are dealing a lot more damage to them than just the Frost weapon would indicate.  Firewind Blades<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3428)</sup> (4+) are phenomenally abusable if you have a way to add to damage instances that aren't rolled and aren't attacks (see the Radiant One<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/epicdestiny.aspx?id=157)</sup> Epic Destiny, for example).  Harmony Blades<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1507)</sup> and Reaper's Weapons<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=2148)</sup> (both 4+) are great ways to abuse crit-fishing- if you can get a way to double roll all your attacks, an expanded crit-range, and many attacks, you can spawn more off of critical hits.  Radiant Weapons<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=2128)</sup> at 15+ give you not only a change to Radiant (check out the level 16 feature of the Morninglord<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=89)</sup> PP to find out why that's good), but also an Item bonus to damage, freeing up your Arms spot.

Just to turn away from melee strikers, for a moment, Shimmering Armor<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=2491)</sup> (4+) lets you avoid Opportunity Attacks.  A Staff of Sleep and Charm<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=2626)</sup> (3+) is a dream power for just about any controller wizard.  And Ironscar Rods<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1656)</sup> (3+), Unforgettable Cudgels<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=2954)</sup> (8+), and Crusader's Weapons<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=991)</sup> (9+) make Dizzying Mace[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1747) builds come to life- or, in the latter's case, providing a Morninglord Controller a lot of room for awesomeness, no matter what powers they take.

There are a handful of items considered to be very powerful that only exist in a level 25 or higher form, and many of them are Rares (i.e. you shouldn't be getting more than one).  If you have a way of negating immunity to poison, for example, the level 27 Sword of Black Ice<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=2747)</sup> – an Uncommon – is phenomenal – when you hit with it, you deal rolled damage, so you're basically getting additional damage instances (sadly of poison, but if you have a way to deal with that, you're golden).  At 28, you have Boots of Teleportation<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=769)</sup>, giving you at-will teleportation (though some builds will have that already).  And at 29, you have the 2 most powerful rings in the game, both Rare – Ring of Free Time<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=2220)</sup> and Opal Ring of Remembrance<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1934)</sup>.  The former gives you extra actions (as many as one per turn) and a nice little resistance, while the latter gives a relatively broad Item bonus to some attacks and skill checks, as well as a daily power to regain another power, which is always great.

In short, high level play isn't really about the items- most of the best items are things you'll have picked up through Heroic and Paragon and still be upgrading, with a few supplemental great ones towards the end.

Answer (score 2):

Use [DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx), choose "Items" from the dropdown, in filters, enter "30" to "30" in the level, and click apply. All Level 30 items will then appear, with their associated book.

Comment: I did this, but check out my comment on my post, on which items im talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried *Adventurer's Vault* or *Mordenkainen's Magnificent Emporium*?

There is *Agile Armor +6* that gives you an item bonus to AC equal to your Dexterity modifier + 3, unless you're bloodied.

ALso, you can find *Flame Tongue Weapon +6*. +6d8 fire damage on a crit, +6 attack and damage, your untyped damage becomes fire damage, you gain resistance to fire 15, and so on.

Comment: These are valid answers but is there a more of a single place where to find items? I know thats what the compendium is but it seems to be missing quiet a few items that I have found in other places.

Comment: Which items are missing?